# Cocos2D iPhone - Handling Touches Correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am not a newbie to Cocos2D but I am building quite an advanced HUD with several sliding and overlapping CCLayer and CCMenu/CCMenuItemImage objects.

They are all responding to touches correctly in turn. However when things overlap, it seems the buttons underneath take priority over the things on the top, no matter what order I add them to the world.

Indeed, even implementing the `registerWithTouchDispatcher` method and returning YES/NO `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:` seems not to have the correct effect. It also appears that `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:` is then called on all buttons/menus in the world rather than just those underneath the touch.

I'd really like advice on a reliable way to detect and consume a touch on an object that is top most in the view without anything else hearing about the touch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this commit for develop branch of cocos2d-iphone](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/552fcf5c95e61547a4bece71dee38b79066e75c2)?

v1.0.0-rc3 or earlier doesn't have the mechanism for touch priority. This commit seems to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use tags?  I'm not sure at the moment how to check z order but I would personally probably just use tags.

Comment: Seriously?  A downvote?  For what?  Set tags on all of your items.  Keep track of your items with the tags.  When you are checking your touches, only allow a certain tag to affect change.

Comment: "I'd really like advice on a reliable way to detect and consume a touch on an object that is top most in the view without anything else hearing about the touch." - I'm afraid your answer didn't quite make the grade

Comment: Ok understandable. I see voting down as more of a punishment for completely absurd answers but I guess that is a fault of my own perception. Hopefully you get a better answer.